# the origins of COVID origin

Tags: phrase-meaning

Should the last "origin" be deleted from "the origins of COVID origin"? Or does the phrase have its special meaning? The phrase sounds as if to mean something deeper than the origin of COVID.  I am not sure.

> Daszak told CNN his team had submitted a list of places to visit and people to speak to, receiving no opposition from the Chinese authorities. He said: "We are not running rogue here, we are talking to our hosts. We are in a foreign country, we are guests of China right now. "This is a good, collaborative, scientific approach to understanding more about **the origins of COVID origin**. "Every place we asked to see, everyone we wanted to meet. … So really good."

> Source:   [news.com.au](https://www.news.com.au/lifestyle/health/health-problems/wuhan-covid-investigator-says-who-team-has-found-evidence-about-how-pandemic-started/news-story/ef78a061ce61a367ae1e7d3fbb6cadcc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer - no, it shouldn't be there, it sounds wrong in context.

What you have to allow for is that people make mistakes in *extemporaneous speech*. Your quote comes from the news, and when you point a TV camera at someone and ask them to explain something they are liable to get tongue-tied and make mistakes. So just because someone said it on a TV broadcast doesn't mean they think it correct.

There might be an acceptable context for someone to say that an origin has an origin - for example, if you were talking about a *fictitious* origin story (such as in a novel) and were speaking about the real-life origins of that story.